# In Creating Google Chrome Extensions, can we send message or any data from devtools.js to content script without opening the DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and that includes the following scenario in order to achieve my goal.

- I want to send info from **devtools.js** to **content script** even the **DevTools** is close or not open. Is it possible?! Because in the documentation, devtools.html or any script attached to it are called or executed when the **DevTools** is opened.
- How to access **Console Tab**, **Network Tab** and other tabs then pass the information to the content script?

Is there a way to achieve these two points?

Comment: 1) No. When devtools is closed your devtools.js doesn't run. 2) Define "access".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @wOxxOm what do you mean by "Define access"?

Comment: what i mean in #2 is, for example i call console.log('Info') some where in my code, then how can i get the text 'Info' from my content script?

Comment: There's no special method to access panels so you'll have to use [normal messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kylec i appreciate it. But my question is can I use that devtools extention API even i didn’t open the chrome devtools itself?

For example I want to pass the data output using console.log to content script and display it in the page. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just to give more example:

Example a user installed my extension, then he is developing some web application and he run a console.log() somewhere in his/her code, then that result log, how can I catch that and display in the script that i injected. basically when we console.log a variable in our code we open that devtools and see that log. But here i want to display the output log in the screen when the pages is loaded.

I hope it make sense.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use `chrome.debugger` API to intercept console messages but it'll show a warning in all tabs so a better solution is to hook `console.log` function in [page context](/a/9517879) e.g. replace it without own that remembers the arguments in storage and calls the original function.

Comment: Thanks @wOxOm i will really appreciate if you can create a boilerplate example and add as an Answer so another can benefit as well! Thanks in advance...

Comment: There are existing answers, try searching for these terms e.g. `hooking page functions in extension content script`.

Comment: i did my research also but most of the extensions are using popup page or panel.  like redux and react dev tools. Therefore  DevTools was still opened. My i idea is different. im not sure if it is possible...

Comment: It's possible and googling the terms I suggested in my comment above gives an answer in the top result.